# Не фильтруются store элементы в getters VueX

Tags: vuex

Странная ситуация, в процессе изучения VUEX столкнулся с проблемой. У меня модуль который отвечает за вывод информации в моем случаи это исполнители песен, весь модуль выглядит следующим образом:

```
import Artist from "../../helpers/artist"

export default {
   actions:{
       //получаем с сервера всех артистов
        getArtists({ commit, dispatch })
        {
            //хелпер ассинхроонный
             Artist.index().then((res)=>{
                 //как только данные получены коммитим их используя сеттер или мутатор как он тут называется
                 commit('updates', res.data);
             });
        }

   },
    mutations:{
        //мутатор который обновляет данные - список сразу всех артистов - тупо перезаписывает
        updates(state, payload){
            state.all=payload;
        },
    },
    state:{
        //по факту тут будут храниться все артисты
        all:[],
    },
    getters:{
        //отдаем всех артистов
        artists:state=>state.all,
        //отдаем артиста исходя из slug
        artist: state => slug => state.all.filter(item=>item.slug===slug),
    }
```

при инициализации приложения в app.vue я запускаю метод:

```
this.$store.dispatch('getArtists');
```

и в одном из компонентов вывожу результаты через вычисляемое свойство и v-for и все работает - список всех артистов выводиться:

```
computed:{
             ...mapGetters(['artists']),
            artist(){
                return this.$store.getters.artist('adbydayy');
            },
        },
```

Теперь к проблеме: как видно из отрывка выше кроме списка всех артистов я пытаюсь получить конкретного артиста через slug за это отвечает в вычисляемых свойствах:

```
artist(){
                return this.$store.getters.artist('adbydayy');
            },
```

и у меня ничего не выводиться. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что я обращался к computed свойству artist как к объекту, когда как `artist: state => slug => state.all.filter(item=>item.slug===slug)` возвращала массив с объектами.